# How can I string split to return array in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I got strange behaviour in chrome, (ff & ie works :) )

Observe:

```
 function doSomething(){
   var status = "completed,please fix,qualified,cancel".split(',');
   $('.searchControls .status').html(status.join(','));
 }
```

Uncaught TypeError: Object completed, please fix,qualified,cancel has no method 'join'

How can I fix this? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What's with the `1` argument?

Comment: What does that second argument to `.html` do there? (Not the source of your error, though)

Comment: `split(',')` then `join(',')`?

Comment: it is working here also on chrome http://jsfiddle.net/QCmwh/2/

Comment: You should also know that Why you're receiving that error. Check the answer of @Sergio Tulentsev which had explained a big WHY? and its solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that it's a case of name clashing. There is a `window.status` property that transforms everything to string. Observe:

```
> window.status
 => ""
> var status = 1
 => undefined
> window.status
 => "1"
> var status = ['completed', 'cancel']
 => undefined
> window.status
 => "completed,cancel"
```

Solution: choose another name. `my_status`, for example.

Comment: +1 for Nicely given Trace / Step to reproduce the Bug and then solution. Thumbs up.

Comment: this was also defined inside function. I newer thought that could conflict

Answer (score 0):

I believe window.status is a reserved word and therefore causes errors. Either wrap the scope of the "status" variable to something else than "window" or try renaming the variable, eg.

```
var myStatus = "completed,please fix,qualified,cancel".split(',');
 $('.searchControls .status').html(myStatus.join(','),  1);
```

...and it works.